# Is there a way to create a data type in Haskell with an undetermined number of fields

Tags: haskell, types, csv

I'm trying to read in CSV files where the first row has the names of each column. I then have to edit these files appropriately. I have an idea where when I first read in the file and then create a new datatype called Record, and then all the later records are just instances of this type, now obviously if the program only had to deal with one type of CSV file with a set number of columns this would be easy enough but sadly this won't always be the case.

So my question is can you do something like

```
createRecordClass (x:xs) = data Record {addRecord(x:xs)}
addRecord (x:xs) = x::String, addRecord xs
```

or am I just talking crazy and it would be easier just to have a list to represent everything?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with your problem, and this can vary depending... but I would suggest modeling the operations you can do on these csv files in the abstract, instead of trying to fold them into the program.  Once you have a "magic" data type that corresponds to your csv files, you have to have "magic" functions that abstract over them.  If your type is not magic, then your functions do not need to be.

Comment: What do you do with these CSV files? What datatypes can they contain? How much type-safety do you need here?

Comment: Ordinarily no. Types are a feature of your data that can be checked by the compiler. If the type needs to depend on something read from a file then you can't compile the code before reading the file. If you use template Haskell you get to run some Haskell to generate code *before* the main body of your code is compiled. But that's probably overly complex unless you really really need type safety.

Comment: Don't use only lists, use Data.Map. A CSV file can be represented as [Map String String].

Comment: Sounds like you want a sledgehammer for actually cracking a Nut. If your just interested in defining a data type opposed to “ordinary” lists, you can simply wrap a List in data: data Record = Record [String]. Are you interested in type-safety for the inidivdual columns, i.e. do you want dynamic datatypes like “data Record a b c = Record a b c” for a three-column-CVS-file?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell) to achieve what you want. This is a powerful technique to generate Haskell code via Haskell (similar in intent to macros in lisp).

Since you mentioned that you'd like the csv file's header to create a custom data type, you would need to read in the file and then generate a Data type in Template Haskell. 
A solution I've seen coming closest to what you describe is the CRUD system in [Yesod](http://www.yesodweb.com). Check out their [Persistent](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) package on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-template-0.6.3).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limited set of csv file types at compile time you could write something with template haskell. Eg if you had 2 types of csv file: a logging csv file and an option csv file, and you had the following two sample files:

```
//sample_logger.csv
Date,Action,Succeeded
20110808,print log,true
20110929,save db,false

// sample_options.csv
Option,Value
backgroundColor,green
name,Fred
```

Then you could write a template haskell function that read the first lines of those files and created an `OptionsCSVLine` and `LoggerCSVLine` datatypes, with `readOptionsCVS :: FilePath -> IO [OptionsCSVLine]` and `readLoggerCSV :: FilePath -> IO [LoggerCSVLine]` functions. Eg:

```
-- CSVReader.hs
makeCSVReader :: String -> FilePath -> Q [Dec]
makeCSVReader dataTypeName sampleFilePath = sequence [makeDataType,makeReaderFunc] where
  makeDataType = undefined -- todo
  makeReaderFunc = undefined -- todo


-- main.hs
import CSVReader
makeCVSReader "OptionsCSV" "sample_options.csv"
makeCVSReader "LoggerCSV" "sample_logger.csv"

main = do
 logLines <- readLoggerCSV "some_logger_file.csv"
 print $ map loggerLineDate logLines -- print all the dates in the log file
```

However, if you want to deal with any csv file supplied at run time, then it isn't possible in any way.